# How to Make a ShopifyQL query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, shopify

Shopify recently announced [ShopifyQL](https://shopify.dev/api/shopifyql) for easier accessing of analytics data. However, I'm unclear of how to actually make a ShopifyQL call. They do include an [example](https://shopify.dev/api/shopifyql/example).

```
{
  # "FROM sales SHOW total_sales BY month SINCE -1y UNTIL today" passes a ShopifyQL query to the GraphQL query.
  shopifyqlQuery(query: "FROM sales SHOW total_sales BY month SINCE -1y UNTIL today") {
    __typename
    ... on TableResponse {
      tableData {
        rowData
        columns {
          # Elements in the columns section describe which column properties you want to return.
          name
          dataType
          displayName
        }
      }
    }
    # parseErrors specifies that you want errors returned, if there were any, and which error properties you want to return.
    parseErrors {
      code
      message
      range {
        start {
          line
          character
        }
        end {
          line
          character
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, using the [GraphiQL](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/graphiql-admin-api) tool to run the query hits a number of errors:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Field 'shopifyqlQuery' doesn't exist on type 'QueryRoot'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "query",
        "shopifyqlQuery"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "undefinedField",
        "typeName": "QueryRoot",
        "fieldName": "shopifyqlQuery"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also tried making an authenticated call with the example query above using my app's Node server, but ran into the same issues.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it only works with the unstable version currently:

https://"+shop_name+".myshopify.com/admin/api/unstable/graphql.json

Got a successful response with this.

Comment: You're 100% right - that fixed it for me

Answer (score 0):

Is this still working for you?
https://storename.myshopify.com/admin/api/unstable/graphql.json

This was working for past 6 months. but now it getting access denied.
"code": "ACCESS_DENIED",
"documentation": "https://shopify.dev/api/usage/access-scopes",
"requiredAccess": "`read_reports` access scope, `read_customers` access scope, `read_fulfillments` access scope, `read_inventory` access scope, `read_orders` access scope, `read_products` access scope and `read_all_orders` access scope"
}

Comment: Please don't use answers to ask questions. Rather ask in a comment or create a new issue.